# How to create Voice bubble animation similar to ChatGPT app in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to create the animation similar to the chatgpt app whisper conversation, it would be great if anyone can guide me or help me make how to implement such an animation in flutter

I'm not trying to create a clone but similar looking smooth animation

[Example Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_LZquziNxGp1z0-yGXUCC0qyHSSf8HE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't know why this got so downvoted, but as the only answer says, try to implement it  using lottie animations, there is a lottie package on pub.dev and Rive is also a good option, althiough a bit more complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look about [lottie Animations](https://%20https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=voice%20circle&category=animations),i think that  can help you

than to use any of these with flutter
[use this package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie)

---

or even [Rive](https://rive.app/),

Comment: I think lottie's custom animations maker platform might work
thank you :)